# MouseLeave and Enter on Form

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a form fade away from the taskbar if the user is not currently hovering over the form with the mouse. (The form contains hyperlinks). On the adverse, i want the form to reset to its original position if the mouse comes back to the form. However, for whatever reason, it seems as thought the enter and leave evens fire in sync when either even occurs. If i leave the form with my mouse, both events fire. If i enter the form, both events fire. What is wrong?

```
Sub FormLeave()
        MouseForm = False
        Do Until y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.height + 50
            Sleep(10)
            y = y + 1
            Me.Location = New Point(x, y)
            If MouseForm = True Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop        
    End Sub

    Sub FormEnter()
        MouseForm = True
        Me.Visible = True
        x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width
        y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height
        Me.Location = New Point(x, y)       
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using `AddHandler` to attach the events to these `Sub`s? If so, what do the `AddHandler` statements look like?

Comment: Addhandler Me.MouseLeave, addressof Me.FormLeave and Addhandler Me.MouseEnter, addressof Me.FormEnter

Comment: THe events are working but they are working at the same time. I tested this by placing to msgbox differentiators in both subs. if i mouse enter, both msgbox pop up. if i leave, both msgbox pop up.

Comment: Figured as much, but I've copied-and-pasted those AddHandler statements before, then changed the name of the Sub but not the event, causing both Subs to be called. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation is best done with a timer (i.e. event driven) rather than sleeping.

You have to make sure the cursor has left the boundary of the form, as a leave event is fired on the form when the mouse enters a control within the form.

I added a longer delay when the mouse initially leaves the form as otherwise it is really annoying.

To demonstrate, use this code with a new Windows Forms project. Add controls to the form if you want to confirm it does not misbehave when you put the mouse over a control on the form.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim tim As Timer

    Sub MoveFormAway(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' called on timer tick event
        Dim destY = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - 100

        If y >= destY Then
            tim.Enabled = False
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' interval for form position changes
        tim.Interval = 10
        y += 2
        Me.Location = New Point(x, y)

    End Sub

    Sub FormBodyLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' If the mouse has not left the outside of the form,
        ' i.e. it has entered a control on the form, then exit:
        If Me.ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Cursor.Position)) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If tim Is Nothing OrElse Not tim.Enabled Then
            x = Me.Location.X
            y = Me.Location.Y
            tim = New Timer
            ' initial interval until form starts running away
            tim.Interval = 1000
            AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf MoveFormAway
            tim.Enabled = True
        End If

    End Sub

    Sub FormBodyEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If tim IsNot Nothing Then
            tim.Enabled = False
        End If

        MoveToDefaultPosition()

    End Sub

    Sub AddFormDisappearingHandlers()
        AddHandler Me.MouseEnter, AddressOf FormBodyEnter
        AddHandler Me.MouseLeave, AddressOf FormBodyLeave

    End Sub

    Sub MoveToDefaultPosition()
        x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width
        y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height
        Me.Location = New Point(x, y)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MoveToDefaultPosition()
        AddFormDisappearingHandlers()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        ' Tidy up.
        If tim IsNot Nothing Then
            tim.Dispose()
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```